# Calling method on generic type Dart

Tags: generics, dart

I am trying to get a way to call method on a generic type. But can't find it.

In swift I can write like:

```
protocol SomeGeneric {
    static func createOne() -> Self
    func doSomething()

}

class Foo: SomeGeneric {
    required init() {

    }
    static func createOne() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("Hey this is fooooo")
    }
}

class Bar: SomeGeneric {
    required init() {

    }

    static func createOne() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("Hey this is barrrrrrr")
    }
}

func create<T: SomeGeneric>() -> T {
    return T.createOne()
}

let foo: Foo = create()
let bar: Bar = create()

foo.doSomething() //prints  Hey this is fooooo
bar.doSomething() //prints  Hey this is barrrrrrr
```

In Dart I tried:

```
abstract class SomeGeneric {
  SomeGeneric createOne();
  void doSomething();
}

class Foo extends SomeGeneric {
  @override
  SomeGeneric createOne() {
    return Foo();
  }

  @override
  void doSomething() {
    print("Hey this is fooooo");
  }
}

class Bar extends SomeGeneric {
  @override
  SomeGeneric createOne() {
    return Bar();
  }

  @override
  void doSomething() {
    print("Hey this is barrrrr");
  }
}

T create<T extends SomeGeneric>() {
  return T.createOne();//error: The method 'createOne' isn't defined for the class 'Type'.
}
```

The code gives error `The method 'createOne' isn't defined for the class 'Type'`
How to fix this?. If this is possible, it would save lot of time and tons of lines of code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not possible. In Dart you cannot call static methods through a type-variable because static methods must be resolved at compile-time and type-variables do not have a value until run-time. Dart interfaces are not Swift protocols, they can only specify instance methods.

If you want to parameterize a class with the ability to create a new object of a type, you need to pass a function doing so:

```
void floo<T>(T create(), ...) { 
   ...
   T t = create();
   ...
}
```

You cannot rely on the type variable alone for that.

Comment: ermm... Things are more clear now. But I would expect dart also provide mechanism like swift to call methods in generic types :D (may be in future)

Comment: So if I have `foo<T extends X>()`, I can't call `T.something_defined_by_X`?

Comment: @jeppe No, you cannot. Statics are not inherited, the type bound to `T` might be a subtype of `X` which has no static `something_defined_by_X` member. And even if not, it's simply not allowed by the language.