# Dart json_serializable generic types

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a method that takes a generic JsonSerializable class and fetches it from an endpoint. The dart compiler is complaining that my generic type T does not have a method available. Where am I going wrong here because when I look at JsonConverter, I can see a method toJson that the generic type T must be implementing?

```
/// Get an object of type T from endpoint
Future<T> getSingle<T extends dtj.JsonConverter<T, dynamic>>(String endpoint) async {
  print("Get from: $endpoint");
  final res = await http.get(env.apiUrl + endpoint);

  if (res.statusCode != 200) {
    throw Exception("Could not get from: $endpoint");
  }
  return T.fromJson(res.body);
}
```

Comment: this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901883/calling-method-on-generic-type-dart explains your problem nicely.

Comment: thats great thanks @zabson!